# ICEfaces messages

Tags: icefaces

I have a JSP with a managed bean.
I want to display a message on the page, not related to any component, so, I do not need to use the "for" attribute.

```
My message code:
public void foo(ActionEvent event)
{
 FacesContext context= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
 if(true)
 {
  FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage();
  message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
  message.setSummary("BMW.");
  message.setDetail("BMW detail.");
  context.addMessage("foo", message);
  }
}
```

How do I display this message?

Comment: oops, didn't see that you've already given the answer yourself via comment. Sorry for duplicating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the `<ice:messages />` tag will be the right choice for you.

[ICEfaces ice:messages TLD](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/docs/tld/ice/messages.html)